# how to fetch row index of table in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

```
<tr>
<td><c:out value= "${l+1}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${list.name}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${list.size} MB" /></td>
  <td><img class='imagem_artigo' src='data:image/png;base64,${list.previewUrl}' alt='IMG DESC' width="200" height='200'></td>
  <td><i class="material-icons">edit</i></td> 
  <td><i class="material-icons">delete</i></td>

</tr>
```

I have two icons , for edit and delete . Now I need to fetch the row index so that I can write the onclick function for them.I am using hibernate so I need to fetch the image name so that I can delete it in the database. I'll write the hibernate query in the servlet but I need to send the name of the image to that servlet.

I tried using nashorn.

```
<td><i class="material-icons" onClick='<% nashorn.eval("var i = $(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex; window.location='http://localhost:8080/AdvanceJavaAssignment2/processing.jsp?param=i';"); %>'>edit</i>
```

But this code is not working . Can anyone explain a more efficient and a better way to solve this problem ?

[image: The webpage looks something like this]

Comment: assign id to td like <td id="edit{l}">. Then on click of this use jquery code like var index = $(this).closest('td').find(id);

Comment: @MostchRomi  Do you know how to redirect some very large string to another webpage using jquery ? I am trying to redirect the row index and a very large string to another webpage on click of this button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <button class='delete_click' value="${list.name}">delete</button></td>



 $(".delete_click").on('click', function(e){
                    var u = $(e.currentTarget).val();}
```

or

```
var u = $(e.currentTarget).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex ;}
```

You can try this